# Finding eigenvalues/vectors of a matrix and proving it is not diagonalisable.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I have got the following matrix.
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-7 &4 \\
-9 &5 
\end{pmatrix}$$
I need to find the eigenvalues, eigenvectors and $\textbf{prove}$ that it is not diagonalisable.

I have managed to show that the only eigenvalue is $\lambda=-1$ (from the equation $det(A-\lambda I)=0$). Then I have calculated the only eigenvector, which is $(2,3)$. Now I need to prove that the matrix is not diagonalisable. I think it would be reasonable to prove that if eigenvalues are repeating, then the matrix is not diagonalisable.

Have anyone got any suggestions how to proceed? Thank you very much.

Comment: You pretty much already done it, you just need to understand that you've done it to finalize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if there exists a basis $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$ for $\Bbb R^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$. Here you have a $2\times 2$ matrix and you've shown that every eigenvector is a scalar multiple of $\vec v=(2,3)$. What can you conclude?

Note that your suggestion that "if eigenvalues are repeating, then the matrix is not diagonalizable" is false. For example, the identity matrix $I_n$ has only one eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ and this eigenvalue has algebraic multiplicity $n$. However, $I_n$ is clearly diagonalizable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You mean that I don't have enough eigenvectors for creating columns of the $\textit{change of basis matrix}$?

Comment: @marco11 Yes this is exactly what I'm saying!

Comment: Is this enough to say if they ask (for example during exam) for the proof of this?

Comment: @marco11 I have no idea what the standards are for whatever course you are taking. This is, however, a very standard fact in Linear Algebra. This is a better question for your instructor/professor than for me.

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much for your answer, Overall, I found it very helpful and instructive.